# Apply a function to each row in a data.frame and append the result to the data.frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, apply

It seems like I should either know how to do this or at least find the answer here or elsewhere. Unfortunately neither is working.

I have a data frame of customers where one column is their id and another column is their full address. I want to add 3 columns for each row with the lat, long and county code from a geocode lookup.

That data frame looks like

```
customer_id       fulladdress
     1            123 Main St., Anywhere, FL
     2            321 Oak St., Thisplace, CA
```

I created a geocode function that takes the full address and returns a data frame with lat, long and county columns.

How can I apply my geocode function to each row of the data frame and append the results as 3 columns into the existing data frame so that it looks like this:

```
customer_id       fulladdress                      lat        long     county
     1            123 Main St., Anywhere, FL     33.2345    -92.3333   43754
     2            321 Oak St., Thisplace, CA     25.3333    -120.333   32960
```

I've tried playing with apply and ddply, but I can't seem to figure out what either one is doing. I tried this with ddply but all it does is give me back the original data frame.

```
ddply(customers[1:3,], .(fulladdress), function(x) { geocode(x$fulladdress)})
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `cbind(customers,sapply(geocode(customers$fulladdress)))`?

Comment: or `data.frame(customers, "geocode"=sapply(geocode(customers$fulladdress)))` to name the column in one step.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. Here is what finally worked: cbind(customers, t(sapply(customers$fulladdress,geocode, USE.NAMES=F)))

Comment: You can add that as an answer yourself and accept it to kinda close this question.

Comment: Could you post the geocode funtion?  It sounds pretty interesting and useful.

Comment: I posted the function at https://gist.github.com/1365208. It was working earlier, but I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error" running it right now. Either Infochimps is down or I exceeded my quota while I was playing with it earlier. You'll need to put your infochimps api key into the api.key variable. Then just pass in an address and you'll get out the latitude, longitude and county code.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for putting me on the right track. Here is what finally worked:

```
cbind(customers, t(sapply(customers$fulladdress,geocode, USE.NAMES=F)))
```